# WCF UriTemplate to match base address

Tags: wcf, endpoint, uritemplate, base-address

How I can call an endpoint with the URL address exactly the same as the base address?

```
        string localhost = "http://localhost:1387";
        ServiceHost restHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebService), new Uri(localhost));
        restHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWebService), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new RestBehavior());
        hosts.Add(restHost);
```

This is the Service and I want to call it with http://localhost:1387

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    public Stream GetBase()
    {
       //do action
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In WCF, if you do not set UriTemplate, WCF will add the method name after the base address as the URI of the service call.
This is the interface for my service:

```
    public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result GetUserData(string name);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Result PostUserData(UserData user);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result PutUserData(UserData user);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result DeleteUserData(UserData user);
}
```

This is the help document after the service is started,you can see that even if I don't set UriTemplate, WCF still uses the method name as UriTemplate.So the base address cannot be the same as the address of the calling service.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your question description, I did a demo, this is the interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserService
{        
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IEnumerable<User> GetUser();


    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Create(User user);
}
```

This is my base address:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSGM8.png)

Through the help document, you can see the URI is still different from the base address.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSmmf.png)

Here's some information about the UriTemplate, wish it will be useful for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/uritemplate-and-uritemplatetable